# iPhone X, iOS 12.1.2 - Whatsapp concern

Tags: notifications, whatsapp.app

I am looking for a specific setting within whatsapp. Namely, i wish to set the notifications in a way that the only visible thing is "notification" rather than the current Name+Surname+Notification/content of message (if unlocked). is there a way to set it that way? i went through all the setting and i can't seem to make it work?

thanks guys!

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different! :)  I hope you come to find this site has a lot to offer! In case you haven't already, it's worth taking the time to read the [tour](https://apple.stackexchange.com/tour). All the best!

Answer (score 1):

You can change this option for any installed app in the Notifications section of the iOS Settings app. Tap on the appropriate app; at the bottom of the notifications setting screen, you can disable "Show Previews" (or set it to "When Unlocked") to prevent any details from being shown on your lock screen.